# Passing jQuery InnerFade height value in data attribute

Tags: jquery, html, attributes, fade

I'm using jQuery Innerfade in a number of locations on a new project and I want to be able to pass the container height value dynamically in a data attribute appended to the container as opposed to altering the jQuery for every instance, for example I would like to pass the container height in the HTML as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="fade" data-height="190">
        <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://placehold.it/190x190&text=Brand%201" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://placehold.it/190x190&text=Brand%202" alt=""></a>
        <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://placehold.it/190x190&text=Brand%203" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

And then get the appended height from any instance as follows:

```
$('.fade').innerFade({
    containerHeight: $(this).attr('data-height')+'px'
});
```

What I have above doesn't work but it should give you the gist of what I'm trying to achieve. Basically I want to get the data-height attribute for the element in question.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this...

```
containerHeight: '"' + $('.fade').attr('data-height') + 'px"'
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work... I think my example code is actually wrong, I've amended it to show what I was trying to achieve! Sorry!

Comment: The post your original code and clearly explain where you are trying to get to, this way folks on here can help solve your problem.

Comment: Done but will add some extra detail. :)